# How to programmatically declare different WCF Binding type depending on an if condition?

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

I have a WinForms client that programatically connects to a WCF service. This is how the connection variables are declared...

```
var myBinding = new NetTcpBinding(); 
var myEndpoint = new EndpointAddress(myURI); 
var myChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IService>(myBinding, myEndpoint);
```

However, I want to change it so that I can define "myBinding" (the same variable name) using different classes (not just NetTcpBinding) depending on the result of an if statement.

This is what I want (I know it doesn't work, but please try to understand my intent)

```
if (bindingType == "BasicHttpBinding") { var myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding(); }
if (bindingType == "NetTcpBinding") { var myBinding = new NetTcpBinding(); }
if (bindingType == "WSHttpBinding") { var myBinding = new WSHttpBinding(); }
```

Can anyone tell me how to achieve the same result with a method that works? Again, what I want is to be able to define "myBinding" depending on the result of an if statement. I'm also open to considering alternative suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't guarantee this will work, but try declaring `myBinding` as the [base class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.binding.aspx).

```
string bindingType = "BasicHttpBinding";
System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding myBinding;

if (bindingType == "BasicHttpBinding") { myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding(); }
if (bindingType == "NetTcpBinding") { myBinding = new NetTcpBinding(); }
if (bindingType == "WSHttpBinding") { myBinding = new WSHttpBinding(); }
```

Comment: I was looking to initialize Channels.Binding with BasicHttpBiniding, and it worked perfect for me. thanks.